# components css styling does not change when re-rendering it with different props (rerender())

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to re-render my component with different properties, however, its CSS styling does not change:
I've created a component, which changes the visibility property based on the show prop and saves the prop in a state:

```js
function Component({ show }) {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(show);

    return (
        <div role="presentation" style={{visibility: isActive ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}}></div>
    )
}
```

I want to test, if by passing `show="{true}"` the div gets displayed and vice versa. My test looks like this:

```js
test('able to update props', () => {
    const { rerender } = render(<Component show={true} />);
    const firstQuery = screen.getByRole('presentation');
    expect(firstQuery).not.toBe(null);

    rerender(<Component show={false} />);
    const secondQuery = screen.queryByRole('presentation');
    expect(secondQuery).toBe(null);
});
```

The first expectation passes, however, the second one does not. Jest finds the element, although it should not exist. The following error messages gets thrown:

```js
    Expected: null
    Received: <div role="presentation" style="visibility: visible;" />

      18 |     rerender(<Component show={false} />);
      19 |     const secondQuery = screen.queryByRole('presentation');
    > 20 |     expect(secondQuery).toBe(null);
         |                         ^
      21 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Example.test.jsx:20:25)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
```

It clearly has something to do with the state, if I remove it and directly pass the show prop to the component's child, everything works fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in my opinion the best way to test hidden elements is:

1. to include `{ hidden: true }` in the query  - docs [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/#hidden).
2. check it with `toBeVisible` - docs [here](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobevisible).

And your test code would be like this:

```js
describe("Test", () => {
  it("able to update props", () => {
    const { rerender } = render(<Example show />);
    const firstQuery = screen.queryByRole("presentation");
    expect(firstQuery).toBeVisible();

    rerender(<Example />);
    const secondQuery = screen.queryByRole("presentation", { hidden: true });
    expect(secondQuery).not.toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

But still, I got the same error as you are getting.

I was only able to get successfully  test when I updated the Component to change the `isActive` state through `useEffect`, like this:

```js
function Component({ show }) {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsActive(show);
  }, [show]);

  return (
    <div
      role="presentation"
      style={{ visibility: isActive ? "visible" : "hidden" }}
    />
  );
}
```

With the changes above, the test runs successfully.

So, or we are missing some react/test-library concept or this could be an error and you can open an issue direct in testing-library [github](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/). Probably they will answer you if this is an error (or not) and the best way to resolve it.